# static instance, constructor and GC, rinse, repeat

Tags: android, static

Is it normal and "ok" for a static instance of a class to be GC'ed so much? I built a subset of graphs and once I execute my graphing option in my app, I see the GC and my static instance get wiped.

I'm not having issues, just looking for some learning feedback. This trace test was done on my Galaxy Nexus.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal because your app (a content provider perhaps?) is only kept running by the OS as long as necessary.

Let android do its thing.